# How to create a static build for a project in c++ XE5 embacadero

Tags: c++, build, executable

Does anyone have any idea how to build a stand alone executable in C++ XE5. I go through the project options and it do not seem it's so obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable the following on the Project Options:

- with dynamic RTL (C++ Linker)
- Link with the Delphi Runtime Library (C++ Linker)
- Link with runtime packages (Packages, Runtime Packages)

Comment: should i select the release configuration?

Comment: You can set this options in a special configuration (Say, release) or you can set them as the base options for all of the other configurations. Depends on what you expect from the project in the future. If you want to keep both options then I would create a new option set to apply this. If this is the way this project should be created always, then apply them to the base option set.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, I will try it right away and accept your answer.